# Callback URL for Username Password Flow

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

We are implementing [Username-Password](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm) flow for silent authentication between Salesforce and our legacy system. While setting up the Connected App, Salesforce still asks me the Callback URL. However in the flow, I do not see any need for Callback URL as part of Username-Password process.

Does it matter what Callback URL I provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it doesn't matter what Callback URL I provide. The integration works fine.